# How to compile a single RabbitMQ C example - how to link to the library correctly with gcc

Tags: gcc, compilation

I've installed the [RabbitMQ C AMQP client library](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c) as per the instructions. When you build using cmake it compiles all the examples. What is the correct `gcc` command to just build one of the examples. I don't know how to include the RabbitMQ library. How do I know where it is installed? This command results in errors.

```
gcc -Wall amqp_sendstring.c -o amqp_sendstring
```